# How to use regular expression to retrieve information from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following log line format, the bold parts are changing from line to line and the rest is a pattern (of course line number and time is also changing but not relevant).

Line 1732: 2014-10-12 09:21:26,672 DEBUG [Default_Thread_7] file.name.path.location - [TestStrinn **Sys**/**1**] **SpecificNotification** message arrived from Gateway

I want to be able to retrieve from a line of this exact format the "**Sys**" , the number "**1**" and the "**SpecificNotification**" that are changing variables from line to line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Matches` with the following regex:

```
(\w+)\/(\d+)\]\s+(\w+)
```

Code:

```
string input = @"Line 1732: 2014-10-12 09:21:26,672 DEBUG [Default_Thread_7] file.name.path.location - [TestStrinn Sys/1] SpecificNotification message arrived from Gateway";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(\w+)\/(\d+)\]\s+(\w+)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))  {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

[**C# DEMO**](http://csharppad.com/gist/e21bbc64e2028e62ca0f)

Comment: @Unihedron micro-optimization!

Comment: Thanks, how can I add Grouping? in order to retrieve the information from variable?

Comment: @user2878881 check out the now

Answer (score 2):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture the characters you want. Later you could refer the captured characters through [back-referencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```
String input = @"Line 1732: 2014-10-12 09:21:26,672 DEBUG [Default_Thread_7] file.name.path.location - [TestStrinn Sys/1] SpecificNotification message arrived from Gateway";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\s*Line\s*\d+:\s*.*?\s*file\.name\.path\.location\s*-\s*\[\s*\S+\s*([^\/]*)\/(\d+)\]\s*(\S+)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sys
1
SpecificNotification
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/5mhc2v)